# nested fieldsets

Tags: html, semantics

**Is it semantically correct to represent sub-sections using fieldsets?**

```
= Basic Info =
   First Name: ________
    Last Name: ________

= Address =
Business Name: ________
      Streeet: ________
         City: ________
```

How do you deal with nested form sections? **Isn't there any better way which would also look okay by default?**

Comment: How can you honestly ask about semantics and then dismiss complaints about table-based forms?

Comment: The question has been edited to be completely different, which means the answers no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's semantically correct.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-fieldset-element.html

Comment: thx, would you solve it in the same way? I think it's correct, but I'm not satisfied, I think I'm missing the better way...

Comment: I would, except for the tables then.

Comment: not sure if I'm going to use them in final version, they're rendered using php form helper, so change would be pretty easy, thx for opinion

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-fieldset-element.html at the very bottom they have an example of nesting.

Comment: The important part of the w3 link: "You can also nest fieldsets.  Here is an example (...) that does so".

Answer (score 15):

You basically asked two questions:

If it's semantically correct your example and if you can nest fielset elements.

Some answers given here were wrong.

**It is syntactically correct, but not semantically correct and you can nest fieldset elements.**

It is not semantically correct for the very reason that a form it's not a *presentational* element. Tables are used to display information in rows and columns where you clearly not doing that. A table is not a prop for making good your form and this is how you used it.

Some suggestions you may follow come next.

Referencing the HTML5 standard, I quote from the [Section 4.10.1.1 of the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#writing-a-form%27s-user-interface): "Each part of a form is considered a paragraph, and is typically separated from other parts using p elements."

Should answer the nesting question as well.

The question, I guess, arise from the wish of knowing how to section form content. The answer is with fieldsets. The form itself has a meaning, so "yes", it will be a fieldset that will contain all form elements (and it may be disabled).

Coming back to your example, you will have a fieldset for "registration" and sections of the registration grouped by nested fieldsets, as one such section in your example is the "address".

The "better" way of making a form... it depends and I guess it is another question that will remain open to debates until the HTML5 will be ready and implemented correctly in all browsers.

Comment: This answer seems to me wrong -- possibly because the question was edited after this answer?. Nested fieldsets are _both_ syntactically correct -- ie the spec allows it -- _and_ semantically correct, i.e. it makes good sense and fits with the intention of the spec.

Comment: The nested `<fieldset>` is literally displayed as an example in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element – note that all content about HTML5 at w3.org is obsolete: https://www.w3.org/html/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is an example of nesting [in the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element).

> ```
> <fieldset name="clubfields" disabled>
>  <legend> <label>
>   <input type=checkbox name=club onchange="form.clubfields.disabled = !checked">
>   Use Club Card
>  </label> </legend>
>  <p><label>Name on card: <input name=clubname required></label></p>
>  <fieldset name="numfields">
>   <legend> <label>
>    <input type=radio checked name=clubtype onchange="form.numfields.disabled = !checked">
>    My card has numbers on it
>   </label> </legend>
>   <p><label>Card number: <input name=clubnum required pattern="[-0-9]+"></label></p>
>  </fieldset>
>  <fieldset name="letfields" disabled>
>   <legend> <label>
>    <input type=radio name=clubtype onchange="form.letfields.disabled = !checked">
>    My card has letters on it
>   </label> </legend>
>   <p><label>Card code: <input name=clublet required pattern="[A-Za-z]+"></label></p>
>  </fieldset>
> </fieldset>
> ```